# Changing opacity of transparent image / Changing value of extgstate dictionary

Tags: java, watermark, itext7

I'm trying to implement a invisible watermarking function using itext 7 in java. So far I've managed to implement the embedding of watermark to all pages using the following code:

```
PdfDocument pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(source),new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfdoc);
    PdfCanvas canvas;
    Rectangle pagesize;
    PdfExtGState qrcode = new PdfExtGState();
    qrcode.setFillOpacity(0);                   // sets opacity of watermark.
    byte[] bytearray = convertBI(watermark);
    ImageData imgd = ImageDataFactory.create(bytearray);

    float w = imgd.getWidth() , h = imgd.getHeight();
    float x,y;

    for(int i = 1;i<=pdfdoc.getNumberOfPages();i++)
    {
        PdfPage page = pdfdoc.getPage(i);
        pagesize = page.getPageSizeWithRotation();
        page.setIgnorePageRotationForContent(true);

        x = (pagesize.getLeft() + pagesize.getRight())/ 2;
        y = (pagesize.getTop() + pagesize.getBottom())/ 2;

        canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfdoc.getPage(i));
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.setExtGState(qrcode);


        canvas.addImage(imgd,w,0,0,h,x-(w/2),y-(h/2),true);
        canvas.restoreState();
    }
    doc.close();
```

However I'm having troubles retrieving the watermark. So far I've tried redrawing the page on another canvas and setting the fill opacity but to no avail. The only way I've managed to make the watermark visible through the use of itext-rups and manually changing the value of the extGS as seen here

[image: itextrups-screenshot]

Would anyone be able to advise me on whether it is possible to change the value of the extGState dictionary from code or any alternative methods to achieving the same result?

Update: So I've tried to access the dictionary in code but it just return nulls.

PdfDocument pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(source),new PdfWriter(dest));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfdoc);

```
    for(int pageNo = 1; pageNo<= pdfdoc.getNumberOfPages();pageNo++)
    {
        PdfPage pdfpage = pdfdoc.getPage(pageNo);

        PdfResources rsrc = pdfpage.getResources();
        PdfDictionary pExtGSD = rsrc.getResource(PdfName.ExtGState);
        if(!pExtGSD.isEmpty())
        {
        System.out.println(pExtGSD.getAsFloat(new PdfName("/Gs1")));
        }
    }
    doc.close();
```

Comment: Of course it's *possible to change the value of the extGState dictionary from code*: Retrieve the dictionary, (optionally:) read the old value, set a new value. The more interesting question: How do you plan recognizing the ExtGState resources related to your scheme?

Comment: @mkl Sorry, but I don't get what you mean by the ExtGState resource? do you mean the key/value?